# Go: time.Format: how to understand meaning of '2006-01-02' layout?

Tags: go, time

Given a time variable, I want to print year, month, and day.
From the documentation, it seems that any layout can be used. For example, I don't see difference between layouts 2006-01-02, 2006-10-10, 1999-02-02.

However, only layout 2006-01-02 returns what I expect. 
Where can I find documentation on the meanings of '2006', '01', '02' in the layout?

I played here with different layouts: [go playground: testing layouts](https://play.golang.org/p/LihASulNoM)

Comment: You asked "Where can I find documentation on the meanings of [... some detail] in the layout [of a function f of package p]?" and the answer is always the same: In the documentation of package p (read the full package documentation always!) and the documentation of the function f (also read it; twice). There is no short circuiting for doc: Don't guess, don't assume based on signature and don't experiment solely on function doc: Read the package doc first, then the function doc. Repeat if necessary. Run the examples.

Answer (score 27):

to follow up on Jack's info, see the detailed [examples](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-Time.Format):

```
// The layout string used by the Parse function and Format method
// shows by example how the reference time should be represented.
// We stress that one must show how the reference time is formatted,
// not a time of the user's choosing. Thus each layout string is a
// representation of the time stamp,
//  Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST
// An easy way to remember this value is that it holds, when presented
// in this order, the values (lined up with the elements above):
//    1 2  3  4  5    6  -7
```

this reference time allows us to clarify whether go should parse 01-02-17 as jan 2 2017 or feb 1

Comment: Thank you, this explains everything: "We stress that one must show how the reference time is formatted, not a time of the user's choosing". Sad that such important information is hidden in the example.

Comment: Three hours of googling and getting what seemed like inconsistent errors and this is what pushes my brain into the "OH that's how it works!" moment.
Thank you.

Comment: Sigh, so the Go authors picked a mnemonic for their reference date, but then they made that mnemonic correspond to some nonsensical month-day-hour-minute-second-year-offset order and chose UTC-7 instead of UTC+7.  Huh?

Answer (score 23):

Go’s time formatting unique and different than what you would do in other languages. Instead of having a conventional format to print the date, Go uses the reference date `20060102150405` which seems meaningless but actually has a reason, as it’s `1 2 3 4 5 6` in the Posix date command:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
0   1   2  3  4  5              6
```

In Go layout string is:

```
Jan 2 15:04:05 2006 MST
1   2  3  4  5    6  -7
```

Answer (score 16):

`Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` is the reference time, which means the layout needs to use that exact date. There's [more information here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), but basically by using unique values for each part of a datetime it's able to tell where each part (year, month, etc) actually is automatically.

[Corrected go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5kULop6obM)